# bot framework channel emulator returning unauthorized

Tags: botframework

I have updated my bot to the latest version of bot connector . But I keep getting the error unauthorized on every message I send although the message is received but after that the emulator shows error  . I went with the tutorial at Microsoft website and I am still having the same error , I have commented [Bot Authentication] but still getting unauthorized.

Below is the screenshot from the emulator
[image: Image of the bot channel emulator]

Answer (score 0):

Did you change AppID and AppSecret to MicrosoftAppID and MicrosoftAppPassword in the web.config, as well as updating the MicrosfotAppPassword value?

Comment: I added another entries in the web.config for both MicrosoftappID and MicrosoftappPassword , I am also trying on the template example and it's failing

Comment: I found the answer , its mentioned in the documentation that the app id and app password must be cleared

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer , very weirdly but its written in the documentation (http://docs.botframework.com/en-us/csharp/builder/sdkreference/gettingstarted.html ) , you have to clear the app id and app password values and it will work.